# Read file attribute from appsettings from web.config

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, app-config

In my web.config I have the following

```
<appSettings file="C:\\Config\\myproj\\Appsettings.Config">
```

file attribute doesn't come under NameValueCollection, so how can I read the file attribute?
I want to read this attribute and then perform some operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the file path of the AppSettings file attribute:

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
                    .AppSettings
                    .File;
```